# How to connect to remote using SSH transport

Tags: libgit2, rugged

Let the repository's `origin` remote has an ssh url.
So the following code:

```
remote = Rugged::Remote.lookup(repo, "origin")
remote.connect(:fetch)
```

raises `Rugged::SshError: Cannot set up SSH connection without credentials`.

It looks like `rugged` supports SSH transport, since there is `Rugged::Credentials::SshKey` class and it is possible to provide `:credentials` option for `Repository.clone_at`.
But I don't see any way to provide credentials for `Remote#connect` in a source code. Am I missing something?

And if it's possible to connect over ssh, is there any way to get credentials from ssh-agent?
Seems `libgit2` can query ssh-agent.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, Rugged does not support arbitrary remote operations with credentials, nor does it support the ssh-agent credential type.

https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/pull/304 is/was supposed to sort that out, but has been neglected for some time due to other things having a higher priority, and is now a bit out-of-touch with the latest changes in Rugged. I want to get this fixed asap, and will then update my answer here. I'll also sneak in support for querying the ssh-agent.

Comment: I've checked out that PR, and found that `connect` method is gone. How now one can provide credentials for `ls` method?